# In Multi threaded environment (J2EE Events @Asynchronous annotation) we are getting concurrency issues (JBoss EAP 7)

Tags: jboss-eap-7

1. From the First thread (request coming from UI) we are calling a method annotated with @Asynchronous  5 times in the same request itself
2. This method is there inside the Class annotated with @Named, @Stateless
3. Following is the stacktrace

2018-07-10 05:27:22,171 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 5) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SequenceGenerator for method public java.lang.String com.project.framework.numbering.SequenceGenerator.getNextSequenceNumber(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException: WFLYEJB0241: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on SequenceGenerator - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.project.framework.numbering.SequenceGenerator$$$view26.getNextSequenceNumber(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2147.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.project.framework.numbering.SequenceGenerator$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getNextSequenceNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.project.framework.events.CreateRootIdentityEventProcessor.processEventImpl(CreateRootIdentityEventProcessor.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.project.framework.events.CreateRootIdentityEventProcessor$$$view110.processEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.project.framework.events.ManageIDEventProcessor.processEvent(ManageIDEventProcessor.java:51)
    at com.project.framework.events.ManageIDEventConsumer.handleEventInvocation(ManageIDEventConsumer.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Thanks,
Nagaraju

Comment: By any chance have you defined this class to be `Singleton` as well,what are the rights that you have assigned to `lock(read/write)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@Lock(READ) @Lock(WRITE)` to specify the methods usage.Read would ensure concurrent access without issues but for write once an object has the lock it might again throw this exception,till method is executed.
Check why this method is taking more then `5000MILLISECONDS` to process,speed it up,or alternatively you could also provide annotations:
`@Lock(WRITE)
  @AccessTimeout(value=360000)`
To the specific method with the amount of minimum processing time you are certain is consumed by the method.By default this is defined in milliseconds.

You can also have a look at concurrent access settings:
[Concurrency Settings Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html)

Comment: Hi Sweta,  Thanks for replay.The above comments might be working for Singleton Bean,but in our scenario we are calling a method annotated with Asynchronous and Class annotated with Named, Stateless.Can you please suggest any alternate solution?

Comment: Hi Sweta, we tried with your idea putting Lock(LockType.WRITE) on our method level along with Asynchronous annotation,but we are getting exception,                            Caused by: javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException: WFLYEJB0241: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on SequenceGenerator - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

Comment: You could also try increasing the access timeout once.That might resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried with access timeout also,but issue still exist.

Comment: Did you add access timeout to the same method,what value did you assign to it?

Comment: Yes, I have added access timeout to same method ,                      @Asynchronous
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
@AccessTimeout(value=600000)
 public void handleEventInvocation(@Observes ManageIDEvent event) throws Throwable{

Answer (score 0):

The message `WFLYEJB0241: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on SequenceGenerator` refers to the EJB spec 4.8.5.5.1 for singleton beans.

Java-Doc of `ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException` says:

> This exception indicates that an attempt to concurrently access a stateful session or singleton bean method resulted in a timeout.

The EJB `SequenceGenerator` must be a singleton EJB or a stateful EJB instance called in concurrent.